# TSC TX600 print from android?

Tags: android, thermal-printer

I want to print a Text/barcode label from an android device using TSC -TX600 model(via USB).

from the TSC website, I got the below source code. Hence I created a new android project and added libs/*.jar files as a dependency. then I copied the below at mainActivity.java.

Link: https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/support/support_download/TX200_Series

When I execute this, the Android(code) is communicating with the printer. (the display shows printing) but nothing comes from the printer. could you please where am I messing this? and I also require to send command details( could not find on the internet).

PS: if I click diagnostics options in the printer, the status prints properly. hence, there is no issue in the paper or printer.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.example.tscdll.TSCUSBActivity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TSCUSBActivity TscUSB = new TSCUSBActivity();

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private static PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    private static boolean hasPermissionToCommunicate = false;

    private Button test;
    private TextView tv1;
    private static UsbDevice device;


    IntentFilter filterAttached_and_Detached = new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    // Catches intent indicating if the user grants permission to use the USB device
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            hasPermissionToCommunicate = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
         mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
         registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);


         UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
         HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
         Log.d("Detect ", deviceList.size()+" USB device(s) found");
         Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
         while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
         {
            device = deviceIterator.next();
            if(device.getVendorId() == 4611)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, device.toString(), 0).show();
                break;
            }
         }



         //-----------start-----------
         PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
         mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, 
         new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
         mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

         tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


         test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {

             if(mUsbManager.hasPermission(device))
             {
                 TscUSB.openport(mUsbManager,device);

                 //String status = TscUSB.printerstatus(300);

                 TscUSB.sendcommand("SIZE 3,1\r\n");
                 TscUSB.sendcommand("GAP 0,0\r\n");
                 TscUSB.sendcommand("CLS\r\n");
                 TscUSB.sendcommand("TEXT 100,100,\"3\",0,1,1,\"123456\"\r\n"TscUSB.sendcommand("PRINT 1\r\n");
                 TscUSB.closeport(3000);

             }

         }



        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a syntax error in the code you posted here.

```
TscUSB.sendcommand("TEXT 100,100,\"3\",0,1,1,\"123456\"\r\n"TscUSB.sendcommand("PRINT 1\r\n");
```

It should be like this:

```
TscUSB.sendcommand("TEXT 100,100,\"3\",0,1,1,\"123456\"\r\n"); // <-- previous command ends here
TscUSB.sendcommand("PRINT 1, 1\r\n"); // <-- Add missing argument here
```

Better yet, you can simply use this command:

```
TscUSB.printlabel(1, 1); // <-- Ready made method on TSCUSBActivity class
```

Also, the print command takes 2 mandatory arguments, as per TSPL2 Programming Manual. (Link here: [TSPL2 Programming Manual](https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/DownloadFile/readpdf/support/4356/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf?file_type=0))

[PRINT Command Documentation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TXyz.png)

Comment: Is there a way to print a label that has 2 columns in one row i.e., I have printing label with has label side by side?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal have you find this 2 columns in one row solution?